# Runtime error -2247417848 (80010108)

Tags: wine, windows-10

I'm trying to run two windows programs for programming my amateur radios with Wine on Ubuntu 20.04.4.  The files download without issue.  They install without issue.  But, when I select any menu option within the open program I get a message that says runtime error -2247417848 (80010108) Automation Error.

First, I have no idea what the error message means and second, how do I fix it?  I tried reinstalling the program several times and still get the same error message.

Wine appears to be functioning properly as I have other Windows programs that function as they should.

Comment: What programs are they?

Comment: Are you trying to interact with hardware directly? That won't work over wine since software over wine doesn't have direct control over your devices

Comment: How old is that software? The error message is from VB5/VB6, meaning that an object that is expected to return a specific data type returns a `null` 

Comment: Wine does not support ALL Windows programs. Check with `winehq.org`. This isn't a Ubuntu problem.

Comment: I was trying to run the programming software that came with my ham radio.  It's for an Anytone VHF/UHF radio and essentially a database that gets uploaded to the radio from the software on the computer.  When I try to select a com port is when it kicks me out of the program.  I didn't realize that Wine would not support all Windows programs.  If the program doesn't work with Wine then I've got plan B where I can run it on Virtualbox.